# How I can represent the hexadecimal number?

Tags: c++

I have an array of 4 hexadecimal elements and I want to represent these values into one hexadecimal number

i.e:

```
int arr[4] = {0xD4, 0x9F, 0x2E, 0x4C};   
int result = 0xD49F2E4C;   //The total number
```

I have tried string concatenation but the result is not the same

How to do it...

Comment: [Convert four bytes to Integer using C++](//stackoverflow.com/q/34943835)

Comment: `0xD49F2E4C = 0xD4000000 + 0x009F0000 + 0x00002E00 + 0x0000004C`

Comment: In these cases, mind the endianness, it might be important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not hexadecimal, decimal or anything else, despite the notation you've chosen to use for them in your source code.

They are just *numbers*.

So, use what you'd always use for numbers: arithmetic!

Consider that:

```
0xD49F2E4C = 0xD4000000 + 0x009F0000 + 0x00002E00 + 0x0000004C
```

So, in this case, the bitwise operators are your friends:

```
int result = arr[0] << 24;
result |= arr[1] << 16;
result |= arr[2] << 8;
result |= arr[3];
```

You should make all these things `unsigned`, though, to avoid surprises. In this particular instance, I'd recommend `uint32_t`, so that you also know that the result variable is of the right size.

Comment: Probably better off using an `unsigned long` type for `result`.     Your code assumes a 32-bit `int`, which is common on modern platforms but not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Or fixed width integers, such as ```uint32_t```

Comment: Yes, the code assumes that the type is wide enough for the result.